# Pause and resume git rebase while working on other branches

Tags: git, version-control, rebase

The scenario: I have a couple branches going. One of them's pretty old, so I'm rebasing it on master. Half-way through resolving the numerous conflicts, I realize there's something else I need to get done.

Now I'd like some way to preserve these changes, while I switch to another branch to finish the new task. Once I'm done with that, I want to come back to the branch I was rebasing and continue.

What's the neatest way of doing this? The best I can think of is to stash, and then reapply every time I'm ready to resume. But I'm not a fan of this since I'd have to do it each time I "pause", and it could get easily lost in my stash stack, making me track it each time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can, try and create a second working tree, one where you can switch branches freely.

Your current working tree should be kept solely reserved for your current rebase, with its lengthy conflict resolution.

See "[Multiple working directories with Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30185564/6309)" and the [`git worktree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree) command, to create that second local working tree.

Comment: If you don't have `git worktree`, making a second clone is a useful approximation. But probably better just to install a newer Git. :-)

Comment: Was going to suggest a worktree if nobody had brought it up.

Comment: I'll give that a try! Thanks!

Comment: Goddamn perfect.

Comment: Well, _nearly_. It would be nice to have it somehow work within the same directory so that my virtualenv/rsync/etc could function without issue, but it does solve the main issue

Comment: @notablytipsy I agree, this is one drawback of that approach. A possible way to alleviate said drawback would be to have a symlink to one or the other working tree folder, depending on your current task, in order to maintain the *same* path (for your IDE), while maintaining the ability to switch working trees (by re-routing the symlink to the right folder)